# AsyncStorage.removeItem is not removing the item

Tags: react-native, asyncstorage

There are so many questions available and I have tried almost about 12 different ways but none are working. The most efficient one is:

```
  async function removeItemValue(key) {
    try {
      await AsyncStorage.removeItem(key);
      return true;
    }
    catch (exception) {
      return false;
    }
  }
```

Then I'm calling it as:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    removeItemValue('@cartInfo');  
  }, []);
```

I've tried putting it outside of `useEffect` hook but still no effect. What am I doing wrong?

---

**UPDATE:**

Tried this as well but didn't work:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    removeItemValue('@cartInfo').then(() => { console.log('removed') })
  }, []);
```

Also tried

```
  useEffect(() => {
    AsyncStorage.removeItem('@cartInfo', () => {
      AsyncStorage.getItem('@cartInfo').then((res) => {
        console.log("RES IS: " + res);
      })
    })
  }, []);
```

Still no luck. I'm using v1.12.1 of @react-native-community/async-storage

Comment: You are not awaiting the result of `removeItemValue()` in `useEffect()` you need `removeItemValue().then(() => { console.log('removed')})`. Without a `await` or `then` your code within `removeItemValue` will not run

Comment: I did exactly like `removeItemValue('@cartInfo').then(() => { console.log('removed') })` but it doesn't work. Even I can see the `removed` being printed in the console but still the value is there.

Comment: Can you post more context?  You might not be waiting until it gets removed to access the value.  What happens if you try to get the value in the `then` clause, i.e. `removeItemValue('@cartInfo').then(() => { console.log('removed'); AsyncStorage.getItem('@cartInfo').then(console.log); })`

Comment: @Abe doing so it prints `removed` and then it prints the value that I'm trying to remove i.e. the value that is in `@cartInfo`. Meaning it is not being removed even though the `remove` clause is being executed. For more context I'm not sure what to add, there is a string value in it and I just want to remove it at some point.

Comment: Okay, then it sounds like `removeItemValue` might not be working.  What if you do `AsyncStorage.removeItem('@cartInfo', () => { AsyncStorage.getItem('@cartInfo').then(console.log) });`

Comment: @Abe nope didn't work. I've also updated the question with the latest ones. I get the string printed in the `then` clause `RES IS: MY_STRING` so this `MY_STRING` is not going anywhere.

Comment: @Abe I got a warning though don't think it's related but sharing just in case `Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.`

Comment: Ok.  How are you inserting the value into AsyncStorage?  Is it possible it's getting inserted more than once?

Comment: @Abe yes, it is getting inserted more than once every time the cart is updated I store the latest response in this key and I store it as `AsyncStorage.setItem('@cartInfo', '${JSON.stringify(response)}')`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239255/discussion-between-abe-and-chaudhry-talha).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As we discussed in [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239255/discussion-between-abe-and-chaudhry-talha), `AsyncStorage.removeItem` was actually working, and the issue is that `setItem` was being called too often, so that the value was replaced before being read later in `getItem`.